# i have moved my Files from one server to another server after moving the it is showing some patch errors inline css missing

Tags: mysql, server, magento-1.9, issue-tracking, inline-code

i have moved my Files from one server(Plesk) to another server(Nexcess) after moving the file it is showing some patch errors and i have cleared the errors even after it also it shows there are some inline css missings IS THERE ANY SOLUCTION can you suggest.?

After moving the files plesk server to the Nexcess server i cant able to check all my modules working correctly because it shows that the widget is missing from that particluar page even though i have used the same code which is working in the Plesk serer but its showing the errors.

```
<http://nimb.ws/LOzXwk>?
```

Can anyone tell me the soluction for it also